# Does nesscery for every $V\subseteq A$ open relative to $A$ $f(V)$ is open relative to $B$

Tags: calculus, analysis

> Let $f:A\to B$ continuous function and prove or disprove the following statments.
> a) Does nesscery for every $V\subseteq A$ open relative to $A$ $f(V)$ is open relative to $B$
> b) Does nesscery for every $V\subseteq A$ close relative to $A$ $f(V)$ is close relative to $B$

For b) I think I can choose $A=\mathbb{R}^n$ and setting $f(x)=arctan(x)$ and the image is an open set.
for a) I think it's not true but I don't have an example any hint?

Comment: adding to @Danielwainfleet answer, you should note sets are **NOT doors**, they can be both open and closed (some people call such sets *clopen*) or neither, so you solution to (b) does not prove that the set is not closed.

Comment: @MilosTasic . In "General Topology" by R. Engelking, he uses "open-and-closed".

Comment: AHH okay thank you! this might be a colloquial thing that we laugh at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a). Let $A=B=\Bbb R$ and $f(x)=x^2$ and $V=(-1,1).$ Then $V$ is open in $A$ but $f[V]=[0,1)$ is not open in $B.$

b). Let $A=\Bbb R^2$ and $B=\Bbb R.$ For $(x,y)\in A$ let $f(\,(x,y)\,)=x.$ Then $V=\{(x,1/x):0\ne x\in \Bbb R\}$ is closed in $A$ but $f[V]=\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$ is not closed in B.

A function that maps open (closed) sets to open (closed) sets is called an open (closed) function. Continuous functions need not be open nor closed functions.

If $f:A\to B$ is continuous and $V$ is a compact subset of $A$ then $f[V]$ is a compact subset of $B$. And a compact subset of a Hausdorff space must be closed. So in the example for b) above, we choose a closed non-compact $V$.

Comment: Many books on analysis tacitly assume that the domain $A$ of a function $f$ is an anti-transitive set, i.e. if $V\subset A$ then $V\not\in A$. Set Theory routinely has sets which are not anti-transitive, which can make $f(V)$ ambiguous. I prefer $f[V]=\{f(a): a\in V\}.$

Comment: If $A=B=\Bbb R$ and $f(x)=\min (1, e^x)$ and $V=A$ then $V$ is open and closed in $A$ but $f[V]=(0,1]$ is neither open nor closed in $B$ but $f$ is continuous.